# Novice at Java. Loop to enter height of people and find tallest

Tags: java, for-loop

I am studying loops and am attempting a sample question here to use only a loop to ask the user to enter in the name of the person, height in feet first, then inches and then to find the tallest. I understand how to do the majority of it.

Could anyone point out where I am going wrong? I began writing the code and realised that I can't declare the persons names without knowing how many people the user will enter. I can't get my head around it.

I want to prompt the user with the questions but also update it to person [2], person [3], person [4] etc. depending on how many people they entered in initially.

Apologies for not wording this correctly. Any help is appreciated. I understand lines 10, 11 and 12 are probably wrong.

```
class HeightTest

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int noOfPeople;
        int index;
        int feet;
        int inches;
        String personOne;
        String personTwo;
        String personThree;

        System.out.print("Enter a number of people ");
        noOfPeople = EasyIn.getInt();

        for (index = 1; index <=noOfPeople; index++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the name of person " + index);
            personOne = EasyIn.getString();
            System.out.println("Enter feet portion for " + personOne);
            feet = EasyIn.getInt();
            System.out.println("Enter inches portion for " + personOne);
            inches = EasyIn.getInt();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you're studying loops, you should also be studying **arrays**. The two go hand in hand a lot of the time.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html if you need a refresher. If you don't know what an array is, then you've gotten this assignment way too early. (Or rather, you skipped too much of the book before you got to this problem)

Comment: Thanks. I was just taking Java step by step and this question said to only use a loop, no arrays or methods.

Comment: @Pizzaman are you saying that it explicitly said not to use arrays? Or just that it didn't say to use them? If it just didn't say it explicitly, it also probably didn't say to use variables, but you did that anyway

Comment: @Cruncher Yes. The notes I have go from if statements, char/strings, loops, methods, arrays. I have not reached arrays yet and this is the question given

Comment: @Pizzaman I'm guilty of not reading the question fully :) Travis' answer should be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very good start.  All you need to do now is keep track of the heights that are entered, and compare them to the largest one input so far.  If the height for the current loop iteration is larger than the current largest, store it as the largest.

In pseudocode:

```
int largestHeightInches = 0;
for( i = 1; i <= noOfPeople; index++ ) {
    currentHeightFeet = GetInt();
    currentHeightInches = GetInt();
    currentHeight = currentHeightInches + currrentHeightFeet * 12;

    if( largestHeightInches < currentHeight ) {
        largestHeightInches = currentHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just don't understand how to update the persons name each time in the loop for it to say enter height of [name of person1] =,... height of [name of person2] =,... etc. depending on how many the user wants. Is it possible in just a loop?

Comment: The code you posted above should do that ( I don't have Java on my tablet, so I can't test it myself).  I left it out just to keep the pseudocode short.  If you want to output "[PersonName] is the tallest", you can keep track of a largestHeightName variable, and update that whenever you update largestHeightInches variable.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create an array of Persons to acheive what you want.

Here's a snippet. 
Create a class called Person

```
public class Person
{
        int index;
        int feet;
        int inches;
        String name;
}
```

create a main Test class to contain your main method, and do something like this

```
   public class Main{



 public static void main (String[] args)
{
// get the number of people in noOfPeople as you do now.   

 Person[] pArray= new Person[nOfPeople]


   for(Person p: pArray)
    { 
       System.out.println("Enter the name of person " + index);
                p.name = EasyIn.getString();
    // ...etc
    }
} 
   }
```